# Extension of solution (example)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Assume the IVP

\begin{align}
  \begin{bmatrix} 
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}'   &= \begin{bmatrix} 
           x_{1}^2 \\
           x_{2}+x_1^{-1} \\
         \end{bmatrix}, \quad\begin{bmatrix} 
           x_{1}(0) \\
           x_{2}(0) \\
         \end{bmatrix}   = \begin{bmatrix} 
           1 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

Writing it as
$$
\vec{x}'=\vec{F}(x)$$
we can see that, since all the partial derivatives of $F$ are continuous within a compact interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ near $t=0$ and thus bounded, $F$ satisfies Lipschitz condition locally. So Picard says that there exists a unique solution within this neighborhood.

Also, another theorem states that if $F$ is continuous in some $D$ and $x(t)$ is the solution of the equation for some interval $J$, then $x(t)$ can be extended to a maximum interval $J^* \supset J$.

How can I find the maximum existence interval of this problem's solution?

Comment: I believe it's $J^*=(-\infty,1)$ since $$\lim_{t \to 1^-}x(t)=+\infty$$

Comment: Oh wait, I see that for your solution, $y(0)=0$ which is incompatible with the initial conditions. Am I right?

Comment: I'm still thinking about your argument. My book strongly points out that the maximum existence interval of the solution for this type of problems is $(-\infty,a)$ or $(b,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,\infty)$ depending on whether the initial condition for $x$ is positive, negative or zero. It suggests that the result depends on its sign. The union of the two is not included as a case.